# Pyarrow read remote host hdfs file

Tags: python, hdfs, pyarrow

I followed tuto and guide from pyarrow doc but I still can't use correctly the hdfs file system to get file from my remote host.

pre-requise: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/11.0/python/filesystems.html#filesystem-hdfs
example get file: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/11.0/python/generated/pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem.html#pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem.open_input_file

Here some code of mine:

```
import os
import pyarrow
from pyarrow import fs

os.environ['ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR'] = ""
os.environ["HADOOP_HOME"] = ""
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = ""
os.environ["CLASSPATH"] = ""

hdfs_config = {
     "host" : "myhost",
     "port" : 9443,
     "user" : "me"
}

hdfs = fs.HadoopFileSystem(
    #hdfs_config['host'], 
    "default", # use the core.xml
    hdfs_config['port'], 
    user=hdfs_config['user']
)
```

This part create the pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem with either the remote host I enter or the one in my core.xml file.

But then I have the problem my remote file on path like "/my_group/data/red_wine_quality.csv"

```
with hdfs.open_input_file(data) as f:
    print(f.readall())
```

File not found which is explicite but why is it searching on my local filesystem instead of the one on hdfs.

If use data for a local file it works but that's not what I want.

I tried many examples, hosts but none succeed to read the hdfs files.

Comment: what core.xml is read ?

Comment: it should be the one in path: 

os.environ["HADOOP_HOME"]/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after many tries I found why it didn't work.

First os.environ["HADOOP_HOME"] is useless and wasn't taken in account no matter what I cange the value or the core-xml.

Second to resolve the problem was with the class path not correctly initialized.

following the doc.

```
output = subprocess.run(
    ["hadoop", "classpath", "--glob"], 
    capture_output = True,
    text = True
)

os.environ["CLASSPATH"] = output.stdout
```

did the trick.